# styleClass property always gets overwritten when adding style in theme

Tags: xpages

I am using a theme for my `XPage` application to set global look&feel settings so my configuration for the `viewRoot` looks like this:

```xml
<control dojoTheme="true">
    <name>ViewRoot</name>
    <property>
        <name>pageIcon</name>
        <value>/favicon.ico</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>style</name>
                <value>#{javascript:
                     var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
                    response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=8");
                }</value>
            </property>
            <property mode="concat">
                <name>styleClass</name>
                <value>claro</value>
            </property>
</control>
```

Although I use the `mode="concat",` which I thought just adds (like `array.concat`) my properties to my `viewRoot` but it always overwrites it, so that my `<body>` looks like this:

`<body class="claro"...` instead of:
`<body class="xsp lotusui claro"...`

I experienced this problem with other `<controls>/<properties>` as well.

My current solution is that I set the property value to `xsp lotusui claro` not just only `claro` to prevent my body from loosing all oneui/xsp styles. Anyone got a idea why the mode="concat" is not working in my example? or is this mode for something else?

I could not find a good documentation of all theme properties so if someone got a good link, I would be glad if he could share it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
As I am also working on a XPages Theme at the moment I got more curious and played a little bit with this. As far as I can see your code works perfectly fine . In my Tests I experienced that you can concat a style definition to a pre-defined styleClass. So you can create an XPages and define a body style class like this with a body-styleClass predefined within the XPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" styleClass="mystyle">
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1" themeId="bt"
    styleClass="oink">
</xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Using a Theme you can now add another (or even multiple) styleClasses:

```
<control>
    <name>ViewRoot</name>
    <property mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>claro</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

In your scenario, you want to concat the styleClass definition which is added as "default" styleClass - and this seems to be an issue or conflict. 
So, for now this is my conclusion. If there is anybody else having more and deeper insights I would also be interested in deeper insights into Themes and inheritance in particular.

Old comment:

<s>As far as I know, to only add the attribute, you should set the  override-property of the control to false.</s>

Example (your code changed):

```
<control dojoTheme="true" override="false">
<name>ViewRoot</name>
<property>
    <name>pageIcon</name>
    <value>/favicon.ico</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>style</name>
            <value>#{javascript:
                 var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
                response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=8");
            }</value>
        </property>
        <property mode="concat">
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>claro</value>
        </property>
```

Hope that works and helps,

Michael

Comment: thx but i already tried the `ovverride="false"` attribute but same result.

Comment: Yes it seems that it is not possible to concat a custom style to the default xsp lotusui. At the moment it works fine using `xsp lotusui claro` and i think i will leave it like this, my first thoughts were that i maby run into issues if the default names changes in newer versions of XPage/Notes.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while, but did you remember to "extend" the theme you want to include the original classes from? i.e.:

```
<theme extends="oneui">
  <control….>…</control>…
</theme>
```